# Angular: referencing my data in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am not sure how I pulled this off but I've got an object displaying all my data in the view, but no reference to it in the controller.

I assumed my data was in **$scope** or in **this**, but not that I can find.

This is my view:

```
<script src="controllers/Multiple-Checkboxes.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="tenant.views.surveys.index.display.multiple-checkboxes as vm">
    <h6>{{item}}</h6
    <h6>{{vm.NumberOfColumns.Value}}</h6>
</div>
```

It nicely outputs all the data I want to use in my controller.

This is my controller:

```
    (function () {
        appModule.controller('tenant.views.surveys.index.display.multiple-checkboxes', [
            '$scope', 'abp.services.app.survey',
            function ($scope, surveyService) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.parent = $scope.$parent.$parent.vm;

                console.log(this);
                console.log($scope);
                vm.NumberOfColumns = { Value: 4 };

            }
        ]);
    })();
```

**this** contains nothing except numberOfColumns and parent.

**$scope** contains

```
    b
    $$ChildScope: b()
    $$childHead: b
    $$childTail: b
    $$listenerCount: Object
    $$listeners: Object
    $$nextSibling: null
    $$prevSibling: null
    $$watchers: Array[5]
    $$watchersCount: 26
    $id: 1927
    $parent: m
    vm: Object
    __proto__: m
```

I did find my data, buried way down here:

```
    $$watchers:Array[5]
    0:Object
    1:Object
    2:Object
    3:Object
    4:Object
    eq:false
    exp:(c,e,f,g)
    fn:(a,c,f)
    get:(a)
    last:    "{"title":"Multi check","body":"Check all that apply","response":{"type":{"type":"Multiple     Checkboxes","isDeleted":false,"deleterUserId":null,"deletionTime":null,"lastModificationTime":null,"lastModifierUserId":null,"creationTime":"2016-12-   21T20:01:31.46Z","creatorUserId":null,"id":1},"options":[{"label":"Red","value":"1"},{"label":"Orange","value":"2"},{"label":"Yellow","value":"3"}, {"label":"Green","value":"4"},{"label":"Blue","value":"5"},{"label":"Violet","value":"6"},{"label":"Magenta","value":"7"}],"settings":  [],"isDeleted":false,"deleterUserId":null,"deletionTime":null,"lastModificationTime":null,"lastModifierUserId":null,"creationTime":"2016-12-    21T20:11:59.087Z","creatorUserId":null,"id":120},"controlSettings":null,"surveyTypes":["Product Evaluation","Marketing  Research","Marketing"],"audiences":["Internal","External"],"valid":true,"tags": [],"isDeleted":false,"deleterUserId":null,"deletionTime":null,"lastModificationTime":null,"lastModifierUserId":null,"creationTime":"2016-12-    21T20:11:59.087Z","creatorUserId":null,"id":120,"list":"survey"}"
```

but that can't possibly be the right place to access it.

**[UPDATE]**

This is what is currently being displayed by {{item}}:

```
{"title":"Multi check","body":"Check all that apply","response":{"type":{"type":"Multiple Checkboxes","isDeleted":false,"deleterUserId":null,"deletionTime":null,"lastModificationTime":null,"lastModifierUserId":null,"creationTime":"2016-12-21T20:01:31.46Z","creatorUserId":null,"id":1},"options":[{"label":"Red","value":"1"},{"label":"Orange","value":"2"},{"label":"Yellow","value":"3"},{"label":"Green","value":"4"},{"label":"Blue","value":"5"},{"label":"Violet","value":"6"},{"label":"Magenta","value":"7"}],"settings":[],"isDeleted":false,"deleterUserId":null,"deletionTime":null,"lastModificationTime":null,"lastModifierUserId":null,"creationTime":"2016-12-21T20:11:59.087Z","creatorUserId":null,"id":120},"controlSettings":null,"surveyTypes":["Product Evaluation","Marketing Research","Marketing"],"audiences":["Internal","External"],"valid":true,"tags":[],"isDeleted":false,"deleterUserId":null,"deletionTime":null,"lastModificationTime":null,"lastModifierUserId":null,"creationTime":"2016-12-21T20:11:59.087Z","creatorUserId":null,"id":120,"list":"survey"}
```

I want access to it in my controller.

Comment: What are you calling 'my data' ?

Comment: A large array of stuff I need to render the widget.

Comment: you aren't showing enough here to really understand what is going on, or even really what your problem is.  I *assume* you are asking how you can output `{{item}}` in this view template, and based on what you are showing, I can only *guess* that this template is nested within some other view, which also has a controller;  somewhere in the tree, *something* added `$scope.item`.  Remember, each `ng-controller` reference will create a new `$scope`....

Comment: also, other elements will create `$scope` instances, like `ng-repeat`, for example.

Comment: I've updated the post to show what {{item}} is displaying.

Comment: you still aren't showing enough here for a real answer.  `{{item}}` is clearly being created by a parent `$scope`, and doesn't "belong" to the controller you are saying you want to use it in.  Please try to describe the *entire* application structure, specifically where `item` is coming from in the first place.

Comment: That's what I don't know. The code I posted is not simplified. It *does* work as-is.
True, there is a parent scope, and presumably {{item}} is being populated there. But how does that help me access it in this controller?

Comment: the current `$scope` **isn't** accessing it.  each `$scope` is separate, but covers from the beginning element (eg `<div ng-controller="...">`) to the end (`</div>`), including all the child elements.  if this "view" is wrapped inside some other HTML elements, it can output the `{{item}}` if it was added ***anywhere*** in the tree, even though this *specific controller* can't see the property, because it doesn't "own" it.

Comment: you *can* see it though, through some combination of `$scope.$parent`, though that's not really a good solution.  so again, to tell you how to get the item you want, we would need to see the entire HTML structure.  Seeing that you are using `$scope.$parent.$parent`, you have ***at least*** a *grandparent*, and your HTML is ***at least 3 levels deep***...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131207/discussion-between-claies-and-davec426913).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `controller as vm` syntax and `item` is not prefixed with `vm.`, I'm suspecting the `item` object is in a parent or sibling scope.

We would need to see more of your code (HTML mainly) to help you further.

Comment: so...? whats is the solution

Comment: No, the actual data is a large object full of stuff, which is contained in **{{item}}** in the view. I see all of it in the view, but no way to access in the controller.

Comment: Then it's in a parent or a sibling scope, as you are using controller as syntax and `item` is not prefixed by `vm`.

Comment: Assume it is being populated by a parent. How can I access it?
This can give me the parent scope: vm.parent = $scope.$parent.$parent.vm
but it doesn't contain **item**.

Comment: See my answer, above.

Answer (score 0):

The {{item}} in the view was indeed being populated by a parent $scope.

This is a child controller. To access the parent $scope, I used

```
var vm = this;
vm.parent = $scope.$parent;
vm.item = vm.parent.item;
```

then, in the view, switched {{item}} to {{vm.item}}

There is some wisdom out there about **not mixing vm and $scope**, which is generally outlined in this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/131207 but maybe that's for another thread.

(Unless @Claies wants to chime in.)